# How to map inputs to outputs with same output and uniform distribution guarantees?

Tags: hash, rust, mapping, distribution, uniform-distribution

I have a set of inputs (in my case `String`s) of variable size `N`, that I need to map to a set of outputs (in my case indexes of an array) of fixed size `M`. So, I basically need a function like:

```
fn map(input: String) -> usize;
```

I need to guarantee 2 things:

1. For any input `X` I must always return the same output `Y`. For example: every time I pass the string `"hello"` to my function the returned value must always be the same, for example `1`.
2. The distribution of the values returned must be uniform, that is, for an infinite number of inputs, the average of the same returned values must be the same. For example, if I have `M = 4` different values to return, and I have `N = 100` different inputs, the number of inputs mapped to each output must be ideally equal to `25`.

I came up with the following piece of code:

```
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

fn main() {
    let bucket = Bucket::new(5);
    let inputs = ["hello", "world", "house", "hi"];

    for input in &inputs {
        let output = bucket.get(input);
        assert_eq!(output, bucket.get(input));
        println!("{} -> {}", input, output);
    }
}

pub struct Bucket {
    values: Vec<usize>,
}

impl Bucket {
    pub fn new(size: usize) -> Self {
        let values = (0..size).collect();
        Bucket { values }
    }

    pub fn get<T: Hash>(&self, id: &T) -> usize {
        let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
        Hash::hash(id, &mut hasher);
        let index = (hasher.finish() % self.values.len() as u64) as usize;
        self.values[index]
    }
}
```

[Link to Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e26cf02bd919a75379221f6b7928f7a)

I think that the above code guarantees the 1st point (always same output for same input), but not necessarily the 2nd (uniformity of the distribution).

Is there a fast implementation of such a function so that both points are guaranteed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct that the 1st point is ok with your implementation.

Regarding the 2nd point: It depends on what `DefaultHasher` does. In practice it may be good enough, but there is another technique that will lead to your requirement fulfilled:

- Have a counter `m`, initially 0.
- Have a `HashMap` mapping `String` to `usize`.
- Whenever you want to `get` the result, look up the given string in the `HashMap`:

  - If the string is already present, return the associated value.
  - If the string is not already present:
  - Add a new entry to the `HashMap` that maps the given string to the current value of `m`.
  - Increment `m` by 1.
  - If `m==M`, reset m to 0.

Comment: this need O(N) memory

Comment: The problem with this approach, if I'm not mistaken, is that I would need to make the `Bucket::get` operation a mutable operation, taking `&mut self` in order to increase this counter, which in a multi-threaded context would require a write lock with a mutex, that would slow down the impl substantially.

Comment: @gliderkite Are the inputs/outputs given as a whole? If so, you could do all this as a preprocessing (where mutability should not be that much of a problem).

Comment: Only outputs are given as a whole at startup (fixed), while inputs are not, each new request can present a new input.